# Icon changes not deployed to the ios device / .NET Maui Visual Studio 2022 17.4.2 on Windows 10

Tags: ios, maui, appicon

- Changing the app icon SVG-file in the project file
- Deleting the app from the device
- Delete everything in /obj and /debug
- Rebuild project and deploying it to the ios device
  Still the same icon from the app template (blue, .net label)
- With Visual Studio 2022 for OsX and deploying it to the emulator everything works as expected.

Has anyone a workaround for this under Visual Studio 2022 / Windows 10?

```
<!-- App Icon -->
<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" />
```

Comment: How is the splash screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you use Hot Restart to deploy from Windows to iOS devices? If so, iOS Hot Restart does not currently support using asset catalogs. This is a problem that exists in Xamarin.Forms, and it is the same in Maui. When using Hot Restart, your app will show the default icon and launch screen. When paired to a Mac, or developing on a Mac, your Asset Catalogs will work.

For more details, you can check the official documentation:

[Xamarin Hot Restart | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#:%7E:text=Asset%20Catalogs%20are%20currently%20not%20supported.%20When%20using%20Hot%20Restart%2C%20your%20app%20will%20show%20the%20default%20icon%20and%20launch%20screen%20for%20Xamarin%20apps.%20When%20paired%20to%20a%20Mac%2C%20or%20developing%20on%20a%20Mac%2C%20your%20Asset%20Catalogs%20will%20work.)

[Maui Hot Restart | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/deployment/hot-restart?view=net-maui-7.0#:%7E:text=.NET%20MAUI%20apps%20that%20use%20iOS%20asset%20catalogs%20are%20currently%20unsupported%20by%20hot%20restart.)

Comment: Thanks again, i am now using my mac for builds and everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your response! If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. Thanks in advance!